# What Tools are best suited for viewing Semantic Logs with Azure Table Sink?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-table-storage, semantic-logging, nosql

I've setup my application to use Semantic Logging and Azure sink. What I see in the tables looks great and I'm pretty happy with what I'm seeing.

My issue is that I'd really like to filter and search these logs.

For example, I am currently logging a method that parses a json message and acts accordingly. There are serveral important aspects to the parsing where I can log important information. All these entries share a message ID. I'd like to be able to easily sort by this ID. I have other field that do the same thing but at different levels.

Are there any tools I can use with Azure Storage that would allow me to perform this sort of filtering on my semantic logs? (Best I've found so far is LINQPad)

Answer (score 0):

Table Storage is a key/value data store, with discrete searches for specific keyed items (well, a composite key of partitionkey+rowkey). Sorting (since you mentioned needing sorting) would need to take place client-side, and searching on properties in the *value* portion of your entities would result in partition-scans or table-scans.

You can use whatever tool you like, understanding the search limitations of Table Storage. And there's also the option of importing data into a database engine more suitable for the type of search operations you need to perform. Unfortunately, tool/database engine recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow.